# Remove edit item link on magento2 checkout page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm attempting to remove the edit item link on the magento 2 checkout page. I have tried removing the block in `checkout_cart_index.xml` and `checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml` using the code below however this does not seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.edit" remove="true" />
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to successfully remove the edit button for all products you need to remove the block for each product type like so:

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.virtual.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.giftcard.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.grouped.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.downloadable.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.bundle.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
</body>
```

This can be done by extending 'public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml' into your theme:

public_html/app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

Comment: this worked for me on 2.3.x

Answer (score 2):

The suggested answers did not work for me (Magento 2.3). I ended up using this file:

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

The file looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.virtual.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.giftcard.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.grouped.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.downloadable.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.bundle.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to also target the **default action** to delete the edit link.

Inside `checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml` add the following code to remove the edit link:

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.edit" remove="true" />
</body>
```

Comment: I extended the `checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml` and added the two reference as stated above but nothing happens. I'm on magento 2.3.